# AngularJS - multiple layouts

Tags: layout, angularjs

I am just starting with AngularJS, which I know is meant to be an SPA. For the app we are building, all of the pages--except the index page--will have a two-column layout. We'd like the index page, however, to be a one-column, fullwidth page. Is this functionality possible with AngularJS?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest posting a plunkr or jsfiddle, since I'm not sure I'm actually answering your question, or if there's more to your question I'm missing.

If you're doing all the pages via routing (ng-view), then just apply classes to differentiate the style for that one-column version. Something like:

```
.column_1, .column_2 { margin: 0; width: 50%; float: left; }
#firstpage .column_1, #firstpage .column_2 { margin: 0; width: 100%; float: none; }
```

and then in the html (on that firstpage only), wrap everything in div id="firstpage". Don't include that div in the routed pages, and the style will only apply for the first page. Or if you have some other set up, you can always use styles around the ng-view, too:

```
<div class="classname">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

If you've got a side-column that's sitting outside your ng-view and that's what you want to turn off/on, then I'd suggest including the class on the first page (to make it go full-width), and at the same time use some kind of logic with ng-hide/ng-show on that first column.